# Creating and decomposing a daily time series

Tags: r, forecasting, stock, arima

I have a number of observations for a stock price from 2017-07-28 to 2020-07-12 amounting to 743 entries. If I run the `class` command the output is `xts` and `zoo`. Since I want to implement an arima model, I am trying to decompose the `ts` using the decompose command. The code I used is

```
data.ts <- ts(stockprice, start = c(2017,07), frequency = 365.25)
price.de <- decompose(data.ts)
```

If I plot the results however this is what I get is

[image]

I find the random part really weird so I think I made a mistake here. Could it be because the data is not really daily but only recorded on the days the market is open (working days)?

Comment: Sure, I'll post only a few rows from the head and the last in the tail otherwise it would be too long.                                         structure(c(335.070007, 323.470001, 319.570007, 325.890015, 347.089996),..... 
356.910004, 355.170013, 365.220001, 363.529999, 355.399994, 357.869995      1593561600, 1593648000, 1593993600, 1594080000, 1594166400, 1594252800, 
1594339200), tzone = "UTC", tclass = "Date"), class = c("xts", 
"zoo"), src = "yahoo", updated = structure(1594647109.52372, class = c("POSIXct", 
"POSIXt")), .Dim = c(743L, 1L), .Dimnames = list(NULL, "STOCK.Close"))

Comment: Hope it is clear

Comment: Try using the function `stl`, a much more sophisticated function for time series decomposition.